# Where are saved the Additional MySQL Access Hosts Cpanel

Tags: mysql, ssh, cpanel, hosts

I have faced a probleme qith my cpanel , I try to add the Additional MySQL Access Hosts but I got an error , so I need to edit that manually throught SSH , if someone could tell me where is saved this information , I can edit it and add my additional Host

Thanks

Comment: Do you ask for specific MySQL users or for a (firewall) rule to connect to mysql from any host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you're looking for is stored in `` `mysql`.`user` ``.

It might be easier to use a separate GRANT statement (which will create a new user if it doesn't exist) for a specific host. You may also use a host wildcard (%).

```
GRANT [YOUR RIGHTS] ON *.`YOURSCHEMA` TO `YOURUSER`@`HOST` IDENTIFIED BY 'USERPASSWORD';
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html for additional information.